# Java compareTo method fails

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a class called task which I want to get in a PriorityQueue.

My class is comparable by the **date** and a boolean field called **isUrgent**

```
 @Override
        public int compareTo(Task task) {
            int x = 0;
            if (!isUrgent && task.isUrgent)
                x=1;
            else if (isUrgent && !task.isUrgent)
                x=-1;
            else return  date.compareTo(task.date);

            return x +date.compareTo(task.date);
        }
```

First time working with Comparables, when I remove a task from the priority queue it should be removed by the most recent date but if it is urgent then it should be removed first urgent task.

But I get this in the middle of the remove,

```
Task{isUrgent=true, date=Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2020}
Task{isUrgent=true, date=Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2020}
Task{isUrgent=false, date=Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2020}
Task{isUrgent=true, date=Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2030}
Task{isUrgent=false, date=Sat Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2020}
Task{isUrgent=true, date=Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2030}
Task{isUrgent=false, date=Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2030}
Task{isUrgent=false, date=Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 BST 2030}
```

What am I doing wrong in the compareTo method?

Comment: Yes, but I have also changed without the last else statement. And it stays the same

Comment: @ScaryWombat If either of the first 2 conditions are met it will fall thru to that last return. Setting `x=-1/0/1` and then adding to it is weird though. `compareTo` just uses <0, 0 and >0 - not specific values.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Don't worry - I had the same thought and had to squint at it for a few seconds :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you seem to want is to compare tasks by urgency first, then by date. Instead of adding the results of two comparators, you should chain the results, so that the dates of two tasks are only compared if their urgencies are the same (i.e. both are urgent, or both non-urgent).

Fortunately, the `Comparator` class has some useful methods which make it easy to create a comparator that does what you want. Most of the time, including in your use-case, you do not need to actually write your own `compareTo` method. You can use the [`comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method to compare by urgency or date, and you can use [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-) to chain them together. The [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) method allows you to compare the urgencies so that `true` occurs before `false`.

```java
Comparator<Task> cmp =
    Comparator.comparing(t -> t.isUrgent).reversed().thenComparing(t -> t.date);
```

Or using method references (if your class has getter methods):

```java
Comparator<Task> cmp =
    Comparator.comparing(Task::isUrgent).reversed().thenComparing(Task::getDate);
```

You can then create a priority queue which uses this comparator by calling the appropriate `PriorityQueue` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
PriorityQueue<Task> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(cmp);
```

Comment: That's awesome! Didnt know we could chain those methods like that in java. I have tried the comparator before (passing it to the constructor of the PriorityQueue) in a custom comparator but was using the compare method,  which gave me some errors. But this is much easier and more consistent for others to read. Also the reversed method was what I needed before. Thanks very much @kaya3

Answer (score 3):

You're not giving enough weight to your `urgent` flag by returning `x + date.compareTo(task.date)`.

If `x` is -1, and the result of the date comparison is 1, you will return zero.

Additionally, there is no guarantee that the date comparison will return -1, 0, or 1 (even though preliminary tests point out it does). The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) just states:

> **Returns:**
>   the value 0 if the argument `Date` is equal to this `Date`; a value less than 0 if this `Date` is before the `Date` argument; and a
>   value greater than 0 if this `Date` is after the `Date` argument.

An easy fix would be:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Task task) {
    if (!isUrgent && task.isUrgent)
        return 1;
    else if (isUrgent && !task.isUrgent)
        return -1;

    return date.compareTo(task.date);
}
```

Comment: Okay, right. I thought it would always return -1, 0 or 1. Thanks for the clarification. Any other way you would do this without giving weight to the urgent flag?

Comment: I think the solution proposed in the answer you accepted is good. I've added a fix to your code as well in my answer.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it explains why adding the results from two comparators doesn't generally work, and it solves the case where you do want your class to implement `Comparable` (rather than using a comparator), about as cleanly as possible.

Comment: @kaya3 Right back at ya buddy :)

Comment: I have upvoted those answers and acepted the second answer given by Robby. First one states clear what were my problems using 2 comparators in the function. Also the easy fix, works, but then it wouldnt compare for the date when a urgent task is found thats why I was trying with the x weight. The other answer states clear with more cleaner approach. Thanks both of you for the answers.

Comment: @andrecj Logically speaking, both solutions behave exactly the same and will produce the same sorting result, but I have absolutely no problem with you preferring the other one over mine :)